# Difference between 送信【そうしん】 and 通信【つうしん】

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I understand that they both mean to transmit or communicate, but I am having a hard time understanding how they are used. I have seen them both used, for example, on cellphones.

> メッセージを送信【そうしん】 in one messaging app
>
> メッセージを通信【つうしん】 in another messaging app

Is there a difference in the feeling, or is one more "correct"? Can they be used in different contexts, instead of only being used in the same way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

送信 means outbound communication, 受信 means inbound communication, and 通信 means communication in general. We also have a word 送受信, which explicitly refers to communication in both directions.

So メッセージを送信 only means *sending* a message. メッセージを通信 means both *sending* and *receiving* messages.